# How to pass an image from camera/camera roll to a new view after it has been chosen/taken?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have added a camera & photo library to my app, but what I'm trying to do is when some selects the camera, takes a photo, and chooses it, I want it to direct the user to a new viewcontroller and display the image there and not on the current view where the button is?

I have searched on Google but not found anything clear or in swift, and as I have no knowledge of ObjC I wasn't sure if what I was looking at was correct!

Here's my current code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func Camera(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func Images(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imageLoad = UIImagePickerController()
    imageLoad.delegate = self
    imageLoad.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imageLoad.allowsEditing = false


    self.presentViewController(imageLoad, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image:UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above answer, you're trying to set the image to the image view, when you should be trying to set the image to the image of the image view, So, it should be:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Because the self.image is an optional var, you need to unwrap it
    if let image = self.image {
        self.imageView.image = self.image
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign the image to the new view controller:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image:UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let svc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("imageViewer") as! ImageViewController
    svc.image = image

    self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

And then, in the imageViewerController:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Because the self.image is an optional var, you need to unwrap it
    if let image = self.image {
        self.imageView.image = self.image
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. I have done as you said, but I get this error in "imageViewerController"  Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'UIImageView!'     when I add self.imageView = self.image(i'm getting th error at this image) do you know why?

Comment: In the imageViewerController, I also have the image view outlet. and then a var named "image". ( var Image : UIImage? = nil )

Comment: Oh, forgot that image needs to be an optional value, editing my answer.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZK62.png heres a screenshot of what I get, the var has a ? not a !

Comment: define the image var as an optional value, `var image: Image?`

Comment: Sorry for this, its just really frustrating me and I havent been able to fix it all day!! I changed the var, to what you said and tried UIImage instead of Image. but I get another error "use of undeclared type" and when it UIImage I get the same error from before

Comment: I have updated my code above with the code in my other File with the button. maybe I'm missing somethign there?